# FlatList and page scroll problem, how to fix?

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with the homepage with my React Native mobile app.

When I try to scroll the homepage, all the page doesn't scroll but the FlatList scroll but in his container and not all the page.

I try some fixs but it doesn't work like flex:1...

```
renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity 
      style={styles.listItem} 
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("SingleProduct", { product: item })}
    >
      <View style={styles.view}>
        {/* <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.images[0].src }}></Image>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item.price}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item.seller}</Text> */}
        <View style = {styles.ImageProductContainer}>
          <Image style={styles.imageproduct} source={{ uri: item.images[0].src }}></Image>
        </View>
        <Text style={[styles.text, styles.productName]}>{item.name}</Text>
        {
          item.tags.length > 0 ?
          <Text style={[styles.text, styles.italic]}>Boutique : {item.tags[0].name}</Text>
          :
          <Text style={[styles.text, styles.italic]}>Boutique : Julien</Text>
        }
        <Text style={[styles.text, styles.price]}>{item.price}€</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          this.state.products.length && !this.state.loading ?
          <View style={styles.getStartedContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>
              <Text style={styles.dot}>•</Text> Petites Trouvailles <Text style={styles.dot}>•</Text>
            </Text>
            <ImageBackground style={[styles.imagecontainerbg]} source={require('../assets/images/slider.png')}>
              <Text style={[styles.textslideone]}>
                {'Nos créateurs'.toUpperCase()}
                {"\n"}
                <Text style={[styles.textslideonetitle]}>Zizi Jeanmaire</Text>
              </Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.userLogout}>
                <Text style={[styles.textslidetwo]}>Voir les trouvailles</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </ImageBackground>
            <Text style={styles.title}>
              Toutes les trouvailles
            </Text>
            <Text style={[styles.titletwo,styles.marginbottomtitle]}>
              A découvrir sans attendre près de chez vous
            </Text>
            <FlatList
              contentContainerStyle={styles.list} 
              numColumns={2}
              data={this.state.products}
              keyExtractor={ item => item.id.toString() }
              renderItem={this.renderItem}
            />
          </View>
          :
          <View style={styles.loaderContainer}>
            <Image
              source={ require('../assets/images/cart-loading.gif') }
              style={styles.loaderImage}
            />
          </View>
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6',
  },
  title: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'pacifico', 
    fontSize: 28,
    color: '#333333',
  },
  dot: {
    color: '#eeabcc'
  },
  welcomeContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  getStartedContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  list: {
    alignItems: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  listItem: {
    width: '50%'
  },
  view: {
    padding: 10,
    alignItems: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  ImageProductContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFF8E1',
  },
  imageproduct: {
    width: 100, 
    height: 100,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#F44336'
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  productName: {
    color: '#333333',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: 'pacifico'
  },
  imagecontainerbg: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: '100%', 
    height: 300
  },
  textslideone: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    alignSelf:'center',
    fontSize: 16,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    color: "black",
    width: 220,
    borderRadius: 10
  },
  textslideonetitle: {
    paddingBottom: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'pacifico', 
    fontSize: 28,
    color: '#333333'
  },
  marginbottomtitle: {
    marginBottom: 30
  },
  textslidetwo: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    alignSelf:'center',
    fontSize: 14,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#eeabcc",
    color: "white",
    width: 220,
    borderRadius: 10
  },
  bold: {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  italic: {
    fontStyle: 'italic'
  },
  price: {
    color: '#eeabcc',
    fontSize: 34,
    fontFamily: 'pacifico'
  },
  loaderContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  loaderImage: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  },
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSFaA.jpg)

Can someone help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you actually want to do, I mean do you want the flatlist to sroll to full height and currently the scroll is working in the flatlist area only?

Comment: hi,do you try `scrollEnabled={true}` in Flatlist props?

Comment: I just went through your questions, seems like you don't accept answers. when people answer your questions please accept them (the right ones) by clicking the right arrow (check mark) next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `flex: 1`

use:

```
<FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
    {...otherProps}
/>
```

Comment: from what I understood the page doesn't scroll not flatlist.

Comment: By default a flatlist uses the all the properties of a scrollview

Comment: from the question, flatlist seems to work but not the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html), to make the screen scrollable.

```
render() {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.products.length && !this.state.loading ? (
          <View style={styles.getStartedContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>
              <Text style={styles.dot}>•</Text> Petites Trouvailles{' '}
              <Text style={styles.dot}>•</Text>
            </Text>
            <ImageBackground
              style={[styles.imagecontainerbg]}
              source={require('../assets/images/slider.png')}
            >
              <Text style={[styles.textslideone]}>
                {'Nos créateurs'.toUpperCase()}
                {'\n'}
                <Text style={[styles.textslideonetitle]}>Zizi Jeanmaire</Text>
              </Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.userLogout}>
                <Text style={[styles.textslidetwo]}>Voir les trouvailles</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </ImageBackground>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Toutes les trouvailles</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.titletwo, styles.marginbottomtitle]}>
              A découvrir sans attendre près de chez vous
            </Text>
            <FlatList
              contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
              numColumns={2}
              data={this.state.products}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
              renderItem={this.renderItem}
            />
          </View>
        ) : (
          <View style={styles.loaderContainer}>
            <Image
              source={require('../assets/images/cart-loading.gif')}
              style={styles.loaderImage}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```